# Experienced multiple BSOD's in the past 4 days and I can't seem to fix it

Tags: memory, drivers, bios, bsod, minidumps

My PC is running Windows 10.

I have

- updated all my drivers
- did SFC
- and DISM (which would sometimes repair corrupt files)
- reset my Windows but kept personal files
- ran Memory Diagnostics Tool with 1 stick at a time with no issues found (also tested each RAM slot)
- updated my bios
- cleared CMOS
- and used Driver Verifier Manager multiple times and it found one of the culprits and removed them. it was my logitech drivers.

But the BSOD's are still happening. I would say that they occur less now but that isn't much relief to me. I've never had this issue before and this PC is only a year old.

I'm fairly certain that it's a driver issue but I put all my non Windows drivers into the Driver Verifier Manager after removing the logitech driver and experienced no BSOD. The issue is that I would get a BSOD when the verifier is off.

Dump file links (Only put the 3 most recent but I can upload the other 2 if requested):
https://mega.nz/file/Cmw0wZ6D#rWweRwXz6WG_6f3u35t6lT28Zug0eC0EzRfLRmtzjqg
https://mega.nz/file/bvpAiJjA#XpL-vStjE5gSHOioO7rCfiWK53kVBR7-efUCIddrS10
https://mega.nz/file/auwimLqK#zDDSZ2y27aat8vY78ExRa3MqLV15U7JSBryzPW2TIH0

Comment: Welcome to Super User, @Nikora! I would like to know exactly how old is your laptop/computer. Also tell whether you have HDD or SSD.

Comment: @saaranshgarg It's a year old and I have two NVME SSD.

Comment: If your laptop is in warranty, I would suggest you to contact the company

Comment: @saaranshgarg It's not a laptop. It's a PC built by me.